# Moving SearchBar table view

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uisearchbar

I have a search bar and a search display controller with the associated methods implemented. In my `xib`, I have a text field above this search bar. I want the table view that appears to appear below my search bar and not to cover the search bar or the text field above it.

**I have tried this:**

```
self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 247, 320, 400);
```

But this doesn't seem to have any effect. How do I set the `UITableView` position?

OK - with doing this -

```
- (void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller didShowSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 200, 320, 400);
```

}

The table is appearing below the search bar, but for some reason I cannot click the text field above. I think that is happening because said field is still being covered by the table view and the reason I think this is because when I click on the search bar and begin typing a grey area appears that covers everything.

Comment: That gray area supposed to be overlay UITableView showing search result. Try adding an initial tableView from xib interface and use the synthesized property in your SearchDisplayController methods.

Answer (score 0):

try setting frame in controller

```
- (void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller didShowSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
     if ( [controller.searchBar.superview isKindOfClass: [UITableView class]] )
 {
    UITableView* staticTableView = (UITableView*)controller.searchBar.superview;

    CGRect f = [tableView.superview convertRect: staticTableView.frame fromView: staticTableView.superview];
    CGRect s = controller.searchBar.frame;
    CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(f.origin.x,
                                 f.origin.y + s.size.height,
                                 f.size.width,
                                 f.size.height - s.size.height);

    tableView.frame = newFrame;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An old question but I thought I'd answer anyway in the hope it might help someone else -I had the same issue and calling scrollRect whenever the search string/results were updated worked - you need a reference to the view controller (self.displayController in this case) which displays the search results.

```
    [self.displayController.tableView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1) 
                                                 animated:NO];
```